# transformer, linear layer after attention

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, attention, transformers

My question regards this image:

[image]

It seems that after the multi head attention there is a linear layer as they mention also from here:
[image]

the linearity is given by the weights W^{o}. my quesion is: for the decoder, doesn't this linear layer mess up with the masking of the attention? I mean, if each token from the attention layer should not depend from the next tokens then these weights seem to mess up the whole thing or they don't? Indeed these linear weights will learn the dependencies among all the tokens and during inference could there be a problem, maybe(?). Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear layer processes each element in the sequence independently, there is no interaction between them. Therefore information about future tokens is not available, also during training. Interaction/information exchange between tokens only occurs in the attention layers (hence we need masking)*

(* I have not really looked into the normalization layers but I guess that there is no interaction between elements there either. Note that transformers use layer normalization and not batch normalization where elements influence each other.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ah! you mean that there is an independent linear layer for each token after the concatenation? Because in this way it makes more sense. Even if the layer is the same for each token acting as a sort of convolutional layer, in this way indeed there is no interaction among the tokens. If this is the answer then your answer is the most complete and the clearest. This was what i didn't get.

Answer (score 1):

> my quesion is: for the decoder, doesn't this linear layer mess up with the masking of the attention?

You know already that the answer is NO, because masked self attention goes before multi head attention with three inputs.

> Indeed these linear weights will learn the dependencies among all the tokens and during inference could there be a problem, maybe(?).

I found that this paper you mentioned works with language translation task:

1. Transformer simplified is Encoder (E) and Decoder (D) part.
2. Both encoder and decoder do have FFNN (read: memory) and self attention (read: contextual memory)
3. The model from the paper knows 50k words and can process 768 tokens from once (iteration)
4. Training time **words** are encoded and go to both E and D.
5. FFNN and Self Attention layers are learning while training.
6. Inference time we put the foreign language sentence  (768 tokens max) to the E part and D part should start with empty sequence just having the start token and we should get the next word at red O, which we will use to improve our D token in the next step.

[image]

N was 6 in the paper so these are dense (linear) layers are learning the sentence language probabilities. Self attention layers are used to for instance to understand the pronouns. For instance in the sentence:

```
Chicken is walking on a road, it is ...
```

The "it" part should create attention to the Chicken and to the road.

Self attention is achieved using the dot product. There is another way mentioned in the paper, but it is not that efficient. The idea of the dot product is we actually have the word representation (vector space). This is where the values $V$ live.

If you multiply $QK^T$ this is how you enter that vector space and use softmax to select specific vector from this space that you will dot product with $V$.

To me masking acts as another **regularizer** that can be parametrized similar to *label smoothing and residual dropout*.

$\operatorname{Attention}(Q, K, V, M)=\operatorname{softmax}\left(\frac{Q K^{T}}{\sqrt{d_{k}}} M\right) V$

Comment: I perfectly know how a transformer works, so all this answer seems to me like when a student doesn t know the answer and starts explaining other stuff. I know masking comes before but my question was about the theoretical use of the masking. The masking comes exactly before the softmax inside the attention mechanism, but my question, i repeat, is: the measking is used to avoid to capture the information of the future tokens for the current ones, but applying a linear fully connected matrix after the attention to each output token of the attention seems that messes up the purpose of the mask

Comment: Adding linear layer after any other subpart means let we learn how this subpart behaves. To me your understanding of masking may be correct, but the logic is wrong. I sense the masking is just another regularizer.

Comment: unfortunatly masking is not a regulizer is just a trick to train avoiding problems during inference because you don't know the next tokens yet during inference

Comment: but i will give you a thumbs up anyway because you tried to answer at least, but my doubts remain....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, you are saying final Fully Connected Layer will consider the tokens of future words as well. Please see the image below:

[image]

As we can see in the right image, scaled dot product attention happens before the multiplication by W^o. Now see the left image. Inside the scaled dot product attention, masking is used to nullify the effect of the future positions. Thus, the future tokens are already nullified before final output fully connected layer.

Comment: You’re close to answering the question, and it would help to be a bit more blunt.